# Jquery $(document).ready() sublime snippet not working

Tags: jquery, sublimetext2

I created a sublime snippet that spits out the jquery document ready function.  When I start typing out the tab trigger in a javascript file, it appears in a popup, but when I hit enter or tab, no code appears.  I tried restarting Sublime multiple times, but have had no success.

Here is my snippet code.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $1
});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>jdocr</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the jQuery's `$` with a slash `\`

```
<content><![CDATA[
\$( document ).ready(function() {
    $1
});
]]></content>
```

Hope this helps.